# No module named 'osgeo'

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo, osgeo4w, pyqt4

I have installed GDAL and checked on the command line, it is working and when I run the gdal2tiles.py on the command line it works but when I run the same file gdal2tiles.py with python IDLE, I get "No module named 'osgeo'" error. Can you assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like you have multiple python installations, and GDAL is installed on one and not the other.

Try the following (which I have based upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901373/configuring-python-to-use-additional-locations-for-site-packages)).  Create a text file within your python installation site packages folder `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` called `usrlocal.pth`.  In this text file insert one line giving the path to your second python installation site packages folder which features the GDAL install, for example:

```
C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
```

Comment: I have done the above but now getting different error and also noticed what you mention above regarding two python (27 and 34)

Comment: I removed the second python but still not working...

Comment: You're a wizard Har.. Jimmy

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/include/gdal" GDAL==`gdal-config --version`
```

Comment: It works well in my Mac with Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31) Anaconda.  
Successfully installed GDAL-3.2.0

Comment: @Saroj, would appreciate it if you could explain why this works as it does or point to an explanation somewhere?

Comment: Worked for me, but needed `sudo apt install libgdal-dev` first.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem. I fixed ir by installing python-gdal using synaptic with my Debian Jessie

Comment: Ok, but this question is for Windows OS (check tag osgeo4w). Your answer solves the problem in this OS?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is using easy_install from Python:

```
easy_install gdal
```

Preferably install numpy for array operations first:

```
easy_install numpy
```

For more information about easy_install/setup tools: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well. Finally, I created a new virtualenv using Anaconda following this: [How to Install PyTorch on Windows Step by Step](https://medium.com/@bryant.kou/how-to-install-pytorch-on-windows-step-by-step-cc4d004adb2a).

Next, I just used anaconda prompt to install GDAL, i.e. typed: `conda install GDAL`.
It worked! Pycharm recognises OSGeo now.

Answer (score 0):

For GDAL 3.7.1 built from source using CMake on Ubuntu 20.04, the following worked for me using Python 3.8.10.

`sudo apt-get install python3-gdal`

I was then able to do  `from osgeo import gdal` for my application.